# Fabric JS storing steps in database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fabricjs

This question might be slightly opinionated, sorry in advance for that. Is there any way to store the steps done on a FabricJS canvas in an efficient way? Let's say I am a user and I would like to continue editing my canvas later so I close down the window, and next time I open it we can load all the previous steps from the database? I am considering storing `canvas.toJSON()` into the database, but it is very large, much larger than I need it to be, since the change done is often very small. Is there any function or convention that is shorter and also "loadable" to a canvas? I am considering creating my own convention for this that only store the actual change, i.e. the delta, is that a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR;

You can remove unnecessary (default) object data and compress using `lz-string`

---

The reason the result is so long is that it gives you all the properties including the defaults. So you can get around that by **removing default values**.

This example script removes every object property that has a value of `0` or `null`.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({left: 50,  top: 50, height: 20, width: 20,  fill: 'green'}));
canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({left: 100,  top: 100, radius: 50, fill: 'red'}));

let output = canvas.toJSON();
let copy = {...output, objects:[]};

(output.objects || []).map(object => {
  let objectCopy = {};
  for (let key in object) {
    val = object[key];
    if (val !== null && val !== 0){
        objectCopy[key] = object[key]
    } else {
        // console.log('skipped', key, object[key])
    }
  }
  copy.objects.push(objectCopy);
})
var canvas2 = new fabric.Canvas('d');
canvas2.loadFromJSON(JSON.stringify(canvas));

console.log(JSON.stringify(canvas).length);
console.log(JSON.stringify(copy).length);
```

```css
#canvas-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.3.1/fabric.min.js" integrity="sha512-ACqMrfAtm537AWzgx/xQ57JnFxXeq8RylQMGg4y/e6M2ew4Z8NycE8aId/Bt2ZE+w1gNsox3MgwxKl7SGMRdtA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="canvas-wrapper"><canvas id="c" width="400" height="200" /></div>
<div id="canvas-wrapper"><canvas id="d" width="400" height="200" /></div>
```

This gives us about 20% improvement.

Also, this approach is naive and leaves a lot of room for improvement. It can't handle groups (nested objects), and if you override a default value of 1 to 0 (ie `strokeWidth`), it will ignore it  and lead to a buggy result. So the solution would have to take the full list of default settings for each object type into consideration, but it could easily give you over 50% compressions ratio in common uses.

**The other option** is to use compression library (like `lz-string`) to compress your string result. This can, out-of-the-box, give you a %70-%80 improvement. This is much faster and much more reliable.

The ideal,IMHO, is to do both which could get you down to 5-10% of original

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I tried out your example and it works just fine. I have 2 questions about "the other approach"
1. Will it support nested objects?
2. Is it easy to have the canvas read a JSON that has been `lz-string` compressed? And how would that work?

Comment: Also another off topic question, if I would let say store all these steps under some unique identifier, for example `canvas_session_id` , what is the best database storing architecture to choose? I am considering key-value storing. But perhaps not the best choice, since I assume the read and writes will be equally frequent in my use case.

Comment: if you compress before storing you can un-compress before you load the data. The compressions helps with storing and transmission.

Comment: if you are storing it in a compressed format, key-value should do fine, if you are sending it to a server for data storage, you can do a debounce, where the data is kept locally and uploaded less often. If you want each step kept though, then each step will need to be stored.

Answer (score 0):

You could serialize it at its final place (or initial place, whatever) and then save the delta between the steps so that you can use `Object.assign()` each time you go forward/back in your history.

```
let superBigObj = {a: 100, b: 200, c: 300, d: {hello: "world"}};

let smallObj = Object.assign(superBigObj, {c: 400});

// smallObj is now: {a: 100, b: 200, c: 400, d: {hello: "world"}};
```

The problem will be that you will need to write a de-duper to remove identical properties recursively (or to pull out only the changed properties).

If you're worried about the size in the database then you could do something like `atob` and `btoa` to base64 it

Comment: If I only stick to using `Object.assign()` I will not create any duplicated properties right? Or do you mean if I accidentally assign the same property name to two different things?

Comment: Also with this approach I will have to invent my own storing and loading convention right?

Comment: @Alien13 right -- properties which exist will be overwritten with the new one (so `c` would become `400`).  Things which exist in one but not the other will be added.  This is sloppy when dealing with nested objects but it might be a start.  The other answer looks more Fabric-specific.  And yes you'd have to invent a storing/loading mechanism.  Save the delta by de-duping the object and then `.assign()` that delta to reassemble the thing you de-duped.  Warning though: 
 this will not be very performant.